# Android Activity Unable to start Componentinfo

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

i have tried and google it alot but cant find even single solution for this
when ever i run this on my device it gives the following exception got this tutorial from this site for capturing image with front camera without displaying the picture on screen [here is the link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html)

logcat

```
    04-09 07:35:13.181  12257-12257/com.example22.dell.magicgoodapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example22.dell.magicgoodapp, PID: 12257
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example22.dell.magicgoodapp/com.example22.dell.magicgoodapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
            at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
            at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:469)
            at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:424)
            at com.example22.dell.magicgoodapp.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
     (ActivityThread.java:2302)
              at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
      (ActivityThread.java:2390)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800\
     (ActivityThread.java:151)
              at   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
     (ActivityThread.java:1321)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
              at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
         (ZygoteInit.java:824)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example22.dell.magicgoodapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final static String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Camera camera;
    private int cameraId = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // do we have a camera?
        if (!getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null,
                new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
    }

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

   }
```

PhotoHandler class

```
package com.example22.dell.magicgoodapp;

/**
 * Created by DELL on 1/21/2015.
 */
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {

    private final Context context;

    public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFileDir = getDir();

        if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

            Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "Can't create directory to save image.");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;

        }

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

        String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

        File pictureFile = new File(filename);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "File" + filename + "not saved: "
                    + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private File getDir() {
        File sdDir = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return new File(sdDir, "CameraAPIDemo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you havent decalred permission in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: sir i have mentioned these permission in android manifest file

Comment: @raja121 Be sure also that these permissions are within your manifest tags and not your activity tags, etc.

Comment: its done i was giving permission after the</application> tag i have moved it up and before <application> in manifest and its done

Comment: @raja121 if you are satisfied with the answer kindly accept it

Comment: yes sure i will accept it .. but now its showing  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: restart you phone and check

Comment: when this exception arises when you click button ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69323/discussion-between-raja121-and-moubeen-farooq-warar).

Answer (score 0):

It has already been suggested to check on permissions.

It is also possible that if a camera was not released on one of your other attempts with camera access that it is in a bad state.  This happens in early development.

It is worth restarting the phone with your current setup to see if the camera is held.  Or check the default camera to see if it even loads or gives an error.  This is a good check mechanism.

You currently have a release within the onPause() lifecycle and that should be what you want to be sure to stop it at the right time.  But perhaps you didn't have it that way in initial development and it is now in a bad state.